# Calculating average of specific dict key values Python 3.7.4

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to calculate the overall average for my grades dict. Subject level and subject code does not matter.These are my dicts and lists.

```py
grades = {'INFO100' : 'C','INFO102' : 'B', \
          'INFO125' : 'B','INFO132' : 'A', \
          'INFO180' : '' ,'INFO216' : 'A', \
          'INFO282' : 'C','INFO284' : '' , \
          'ECON100' : 'C','ECON110' : 'C', \
          'ECON218' : '' , 'GEO100' : '' , \
          'GEO113'  : 'D', 'GEO124' : 'D',}

subjects = ['INFO100','INFO102','INFO125',\
           'INFO132','INFO180','INFO216',\
           'INFO282','INFO284','ECON100',\
           'ECON110','ECON218','GEO100' ,\
           'GEO113' ,'GEO124']

subject_code = {'Informatics' : 'INFO',\
                'Economy'     : 'ECON',\
                'Geografi'    : 'GEO'}
```

This is what i have. Not sure where and how to iterate from here on.

```py
convert_grade = {"A": 5, "B": 4, "C": 3, "D": 2, "E": 1, "F": 0}
convert_grade.update({v: k for k,v in convert_grade.items()})
grade_sum = sum(['convert_grade['something'] for 'something' in 'something if 'something' is not None])
average_grade = round(grade_sum / len(['something' for 'something' in 'something' if 'something' is not None]))
print("Average grade:", convert_grade[average_grade])
```

I got help constructing the way to calculate(i think at least, might be a too fancy way) but i don't really know where to iterate from there. I am fairly new to python so i am still learning how to iterate properly. Any help or guidance is more than welcome. I do not need "my" way of calculation to work, i just need help in the right direction.

Comment: _I am trying to calculate the average for all my grades in the grades dictionary using the key values_ <- What does that mean? Do you want to calculate your overall average? Your average by subject code? I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: My overall average for key values in dict grades is what i meant. At first it doesn't matter what the subject code is, nor the subject level (100, 200, 300)

Comment: Do empty strings `''` represent an F or that you haven't taken the class and it shouldn't be part of the average?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grades = {'INFO100' : 'C','INFO102' : 'B', 
          'INFO125' : 'B','INFO132' : 'A', 
          'INFO180' : '' ,'INFO216' : 'A', 
          'INFO282' : 'C','INFO284' : '' , 
          'ECON100' : 'C','ECON110' : 'C', 
          'ECON218' : '' , 'GEO100' : '' , 
          'GEO113'  : 'D', 'GEO124' : 'D',}

total = 0
count = 0

for k, v in grades.items():
        if(v == "A"):
                total += 5
        elif(v == "B"):
                total += 4
        elif(v == "C"):
                total += 3
        elif(v == "D"):
                total += 2
        elif(v == "E"):
                total += 1
        else:
                total += 0

        count += 1

print(total / count)
```

Yields: `2.4285714285714284`

Which is the average of those grades (assuming that blanks count, if you don't want them to count, we can filter them out)

Comment: It would be better if you had a dictionary of grades to integer values instead of a bunch of `elif`'s

Comment: Looks great! I was alternatively working on the same solution, but i just didn't know where to iterate the key value. What value does it count the blanks? 0?

Comment: That's right, it counts `''` as 0. Essentially, if there was no mapping for `A->E`, it counts 0. If it works for you, please feel free to accept :)

Comment: @Boris I will add in a dict comprehension, too. One second.

Comment: @Boris Do you have an example? Could my list comprehension be used?

Comment: `grade_to_score = {'a': 5, 'b': 4, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, '': 0}` and then `total += grade_to_score[v.lower()]`. It's not a good idea to just asign 0 to any value you don't recognize. in the real world someone might double tap a key and enter `AA` instead of `A` and you can't just silently convert that to 0, you should raise an error. Unless this is just a homework assignment you're doing, and not for real life, in which case you could remove the last element of that dictionary and just do `grade_to_score.get(v.lower(), 0)`

Comment: I didn't read the question, I just looked at the answer, looks like you're already doing that @DusanBiga I'll write an answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are adding the reverse relation to the dict with that `convert_grade.update` line. If you're going to need that (you don't, at least for this specific task), you should have two dictionaries. One for the `letter grade -> score` mapping and one for `score -> letter grade`. You should also rename it from `convert_grade` to `grade_to_score` or something more descriptive.

First, if `''` means that you haven't taken the class yet and it shouldn't be counted as part of your average, you have to filter them out first. You were on the right track but don't check for `None` check for the empty string, which you do by just treating the string as a boolean, if it's an empty string it won't evaluate to true:

```
grades = {course: grade for course, grade in grades.items() if grade}
```

Then you need to convert the letter grades to a list of numbers using a dictionary, and then you can find the average of that list using either `sum(x) / len(x)` or [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean):

```
from statistics import mean

grade_to_score = {"A": 5, "B": 4, "C": 3, "D": 2, "E": 1, "F": 0}

average_grade = mean(grade_to_score[grade] for grade in grades.values())
print("Average grade:", average_grade)
```

If  a `''` means that you got an F, you can skip the first step and just add an extra `'': 0` part to your definition of `grades_to_score`.

---

If you want to get averages by course, just filter the dictionary right after the first step

```
info_grades = {course: grade for course, grade in grades.items() if course.startswith('INFO')}
```

and then you can pass `info_grades.values()` instead of `grades.values()` to `statistics.mean()` to get the average of all your Informatics courses. If you want to do every one, have a `for` loop over `['INFO', 'ECON', 'GEO']`.

Comment: Of course, you have to double check that you can't have different courses with the same prefix, like if you have `GE` and `GEO` classes, then with that naive `.startswith()` logic, all the `GEO` classes will be counted in the `GE` class average. You should add a check for that or use a regex to extract the first group of letters.